# Link to user's profile view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I link to a user's profile view without getting a `no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String` error?

What I currently have:

```
- @questions.each do |question|
  = link_to question.user.username,  "/users/"+question.user.id
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is:

When the user clicks on a link, he will get redirected to the original poster's profile page. ex: **localhost:3000/users/1**

Home controller:

```
  def profile
    if !user_signed_in?
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
    if User.find_by_id(params[:id])
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#home'
  devise_for :users
  get "/users/:id" => "home#profile"
  get "home" => "home#feed"
  get "questions" => "home#questions"
  resources :questions
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the id manually to a string:

```
  = link_to question.user.username,  "/users/"+question.user.id.to_s
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Also this one should work.

```
= link_to question.user.username,  "/users/#{question.user.id}"
```